# Http Request response time within C# application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, http, server

I have this method :

```
private string GetCheckResultFor(string url)
        {
            Stopwatch reveil = new Stopwatch();
            reveil.Start();
            HttpWebResponse response = null;
            url = Regex.Replace(url, @"\s+", "");
            if (!url.StartsWith("http") && !url.StartsWith("https")) url = "http://" + url;
            string res = "";
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Method = "GET";
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                if (response.ResponseUri.ToString() == url) res = "No Action";
                else res = "Redirect to " + response.ResponseUri.ToString();
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
                {
                    response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
                    res = "Errorcode: " + (int)response.StatusCode;
                }
                else
                {
                    res = "Error: " + e.Status;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (response != null)
                {
                    response.Close();
                }

            }
            reveil.Stop();
            Debug.WriteLine("For this url : " + url + " = " + reveil.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
            return res;
        }
```

It takes between 200 and 700 ms. I know it depends on internet connection speed but I need to improve it because I only need the reponse url. I have Three possiblities :

- Reponse Url = request Url ==> No action
- Redirect to another url
- Request Error

So How can I edit this snippet to reduce method response time ?

Comment: `request.Method = "GET";` -> `request.Method = "HEAD";` might save you some time and should still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that a webclient with custom settings gave me the fastest result.
Personally I was building a framework for web crawling & scraping, where you want it to do the requests quickly.

Might be an alternative to check out.

```
public class DefaultWebClient : WebClient {
    public DefaultWebClient() {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = Int32.MaxValue;
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address) {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;

        if (request != null) {
            //This might work in your case, it didnt do the trick for me.
            //request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Head;
            request.Proxy = null;
            request.Timeout = 5000;
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        }

        return request;
    }
}
```

This, in combination with retrieving the response url should do the trick.

```
    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request) {
        var response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
        if (response != null) {
            var responseUri = response.ResponseUri;
            // Redirect found.
        }
        else {
            // No Action.
        }

        return response;
    }
```

If you do a lot of requests to get the redirects, it might be a good idea to raise it as an event.